# PHP JSON Decode erroring with valid JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode a simple JSON string and the format to make it look correct. I actually copied the string and decode is with the same algorithm but without all the extra code and it worked fine.

```
print_r(json_decode('{"user_id":1,"issused":"2016-02-24 04:40:17","expire":"2016-03-02 04:40:17"}'));
```

That worked. But when I do

```
$hash = Hash::salt(32);
$issused = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 week'));
$data = array('user_id' => 1, 'issused' => $issused, 'expire' =>     $expire);
$encrypt = Cipher::encrypt(json_encode($data), $hash);
$decrypt = Cipher::decrypt($encrypt, $hash);
echo $encrypt;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $decrypt;
echo "<br><br>";
print_r(json_decode($decrypt));
```

Where `$decrypted` is the valid formated JSON that I posted above. When I used:

```
echo json_last_erro();
```

It gave me an output of 3 which is `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR`

Any idea why this isn't being decoded correctly?

**EDIT**
Here is how I am encrypting data.

```
class Cipher {
public static function encrypt($string, $hash) {
    $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $hash, utf8_encode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    //$encoded = urlencode($encrypted);
    $encoded = base64_encode($encrypted);
    return $encoded;
}

public static function decrypt($string, $hash) {
    //$decoded = urldecode($string);
    $decoded = base64_decode($string);
    $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $hash, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

}

Here how I am creating the salt.

```
public static function salt($length) {
    return mcrypt_create_iv($length); //base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print the content of above line in php?

Comment: what is the library that you have used for generating `salt` and `encrypt` data. There is causing because of character encoding mismatching.

Comment: Extract an example, as per guidelines, and state exactly where things go wrong. Note that volatile things like the date are not suitable for an example, as they change and require human interpretation.

Comment: I am using mcrypt to encrypt a json string and the same mcrypt to decode it

Comment: does your Cipher code work - is `Cipher::decrypt(Cipher::encrypt("test", $hash), $hash)) === "test"` true ? (for all possible strings)

Comment: Yes, they do. Even if they didn't, the string still decrypt to the file it was before encrypted.

Comment: I've just run the above code and it successfully decoded the decrypted JSON. Possibly an environment or configuration issue? I'm running PHP 5.6 on CentOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra control characters (\0) are due to the cypher block padding. From the [mcrypt_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) docs

**data**

- The data that will be decrypted with the given cipher and mode. If
  the size of the data is not n * blocksize, the data will be padded
  with '\0'.

You can pad the input for the block size yourself in the encrypt and then remove the extra padding in decrypt() or you can trim the trailing zero bytes from the decoded message doing the below.

`$decrypt = trim($decrypt, "\0");`